nuxtjs has issue as : vue-ls Storage "local" is not supported your system, use memory storage
I'm running nuxtjs(2) front-end project and facing one issue in my terminal after hitting "npm run dev". I'm not sure, how to fix this? You can see in the screenshot attached.
https://i.sstatic.net/2CQaK.jpg
I tried it with vuex and with try & catch statements as well. It won't work for me![enter image description here][1]

Where is the screenshot? Have you looked up the error on the Internet?

The error likely means what it says, you used vue-ls library the wrong way. This is very specific to your case and cannot be answered in general. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . There's no screenshot, but also check https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors

Hi! Please accept my apology for inconvience. I've added the screenshot please visit the link https://i.sstatic.net/2CQaK.jpg
Yes I've tried my best to get solution and none of them are working for me. @kissu

Regarding the project, it hasn't updated in quite some time. Nowaday you should use Nitro for a storage solution.

Alright! But, there is a lot of issues for using Nitro to run server. Need to update nuxt to3 or 2.17 at least for using bridge. In case of update, need to upgrade a lots of package which leads to broken package, api calls etc. I can't fix multiple changes due to shortage of time frame. Is there any other suggestion? Thanks @kissu

You should upgrade to Nuxt3, but since you cannot I recommend starting here: https://github.com/RobinCK/vue-ls/issues/33 Which browsers and version do you use?

Alright! Upgrading to Nuxt3 is fine and I can understand. But, my question to you is, do you really think this can be a browser's version issue? I'm using Chrome Version 123.0.6312.106 (Official Build) (64-bit) and Microsoft Edge Version 123.0.2420.81 (Official build) (64-bit). @kissu

Do you have the error in both browsers? Feel free to report it in the issue if that's the case.

I got this error only in the terminal, rest is working fine for me.
